# Run Python3 code from PHP

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I have a Python3 script that I would like to call from my webpage. My webhost says they will not add Python3 to their site (their version of python is 2.6.6).

Is there anyway I can run a Python3 script from my webpage if I do not have Python3 installed? I can use Perl to run Python if it would be possible.

Comment: Convert your script from python3 to python2. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run it as it is, obviously, without the python3 interpreter.

You can compile it though (http://www.pyinstaller.org/) and run that from php.

Comment: Will this be able to compile and be ran from php?

Comment: Yes, you compile it (see http://www.pyinstaller.org/) and use it with shell_exec from php (http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).